# How to create teams with team template by using C# SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

While the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples) explains how to create a team with a [team template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/get-started-with-teams-templates#what-are-base-template-types) by using raw HTTP requests, I couldn't find a out-of-the-box solution by using the Graph SDK.

The best match I could find was:

```
serviceClient.Teams.Request().AddAsync(new Team { Template = new TeamsTemplate { Id = "???", ODataType = "???" } });
```

But insert the template names like `standard` or `educationClass` didn't work on any place in the above given request. So any documentation available about how to form the request by using the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this request to create a team with a template:

```
await client.Teams.Request().AddAsync(
      new Team
      {
          DisplayName = "My team",
          Description = "desc",
          AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
          {
              {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
          }
      });
```

Check this [thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/871) for a workaround if your way doesn't work.